# Apache2.4 will not restart after including httpd-ssl.conf

Tags: ssl, openssl, apache2.4

My company has just provided us SSL certificates that I had to attempt to install and configure using Apache2.4 on a Windows Server 2019.

I created a folder called "certs" within the conf folder on Apache24.

Within the certs folder, I have the following certs:

```
MYCOMPANY_Intermediate.cer
MYCOMPANY_Root.cer
mycompany_name_com.cer
private.cer
private.key
```

I have updated the httpd-ssl.conf file to include the certs, as follows:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs"
ServerName mycompany.name.com:443
ServerAdmin mycompany@email.com
ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error-ssl.log"
TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access-ssl.log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
SSLEngine on

#   Server Certificate:
SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/certs/mycompany_name_com.cer"

#   Server Private Key:
SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/certs/private.key"

#   Server Certificate Chain:
SSLCertificateChainFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/certs/MYCOMPANY_Intermediate.cer"

</VirtualHost>
```

Back in the httpd.conf file, when I include the following:

```
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Apache fails to restart.

Within the error log, the only thing noticeable that I am finding is maybe this:

```
[Sat Jan 23 10:56:32.453519 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8552:tid 772] AH00455: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) mod_authnz_sspi/0.1.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jan 23 10:56:32.453519 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8552:tid 772] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Oct  2 2020 11:45:39
[Sat Jan 23 10:56:32.453519 2021] [core:notice] [pid 8552:tid 772] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Sat Jan 23 10:56:32.463520 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8552:tid 772] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 17204
[Sat Jan 23 10:56:33.684738 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 17204:tid 808] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Jan 23 10:56:33.729741 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 17204:tid 808] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

As you will see, there are no errors, just warnings.  I do not know why Apache is failing to restart, and I really need to get this to work.

### Edit

In the Event View, under Windows Log under System, I see the following error:

```
The Apache2.4 service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Incorrect function.
```

I also see an event ID number 7024. I am not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem...

A typo.

Yup, it was a typo.

In the httpd-ssl.conf file, this part:

```
#   Server Certificate:
SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/certs/mycompany_name_com.cer"
```

mycompany_name_com.cer was mispelled.

thecompany_name_com.cer is the correct spelling.